# Mysql time zones select

Tags: mysql

In my application, I need to execute a query like this,

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_AUDITREQUEST WHERE CREATE_DATE >= " + search.getStartDate() + " AND CREATE_DATE =< " + search.getEndDate() + " AND STATUS = '"search.getStatus() +"'";
```

the getStartDate() and getEndDate() of course in date type. Error is,

> **Exception of type com.sap.sql.log.OpenSQLException caught: The SQL
>   statement "SELECT * FROM TBL_AUDITREQUEST WHERE CREATE_DATE >= Thu Mar
>   22 14:11:00 EET 2018" contains the syntax error[s]: - 1:57 - SQL
>   syntax error: the token "MAR" was not expected here**

and the table's data is

[image]

How can I execute a select query that like above ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Transform datetime returned from `getStartDate` and `getEndDate` according into one of supported [MySQL datetime literal formats](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html). "**Thu Mar 22 14:11:00 EET 2018**" is not in supported format.
2. Properly prefix (`TIMESTAMP`) and quote (`'`) the dates:

> SELECT * FROM TBL_AUDITREQUEST WHERE  CREATE_DATE >= TIMESTAMP '" +
>   search.getStartDate() + "'  AND CREATE_DATE =< TIMESTAMP '" +
>   search.getEndDate() + "'  AND STATUS = '" +
>   search.getStatus() + "'";